# NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType: working unreliably

Tags: iphone, ios, nsbundle

I'm working on an app where I drag and drop a folder containing images into my Xcode project.

When the app launches, I gather all the filenames of the images in the app to lazily load them later on:

```
-(NSArray *)fetchImagesInFolder:(NSString *)folderName{

    NSArray *allImagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:nil inDirectory:folderName]];

    if([allImagesArray count] == 0){
        NSLog(@"No images found in %@", folderName);
        return nil;
    }

    return allImagesArray;
}
```

Here's my problem: this only works 1 time out 4. 3 times out of 4, `[allImagesArray count]` is 0.

I then have to delete the folder from the project, drag and drop it again, if I previously had selected "Create groups for any added folders" I'll select "Create folder references for any added folders" and vice versa, clean, build, and run. That solution works 3 times out of 4.

If I right click the .app file that the project produces, and then "Show Package Contents", the images are always there. But then why is `pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:` being so unreliable?

Comment: I believe **Create folder references for any added folders** is always what you should be using.

Comment: When you browser the .app's package contents, the images are always in the subdirectory that you expect?  I've usually handled this explicitly by creating a Copy Files Build Phase and set the subdirectory below `Resources` to whatever name the code expects.

Comment: @alanduncan actually, when browsing the .app's package content the images are not always in the expected subdirectory (but that doesn't always stop it from working). Creating a Copy Files Build Phase sounds like a pretty good idea, I'll try that.

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at your target's Build Phases, 'Copy Bundle Resources' section, and see how the system is moving the images into the bundle? I would expect it to NOT copy the folder itself but to just move the various images into a common directory.

If so, assuming you have all 'jpg' or all 'png', then take the appropriate suffix (say 'jpg') and do this:

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:nil];
```

If in fact you have convinced Xcode to actually create a directory in the bundle, then add the name as you do now but leave the type alone.

If you have a mix of image types, then do the above command once for each time, then combine the arrays into a super array.

EDIT: If you want to have images stored in various folders, I believe that you will need to write a 'Run Script' shell script to do what you want. While I have not done this technique myself, I believe it to be what others are doing with the same problem:

- do not include any of the images in the Target (uncheck all) - you will manage them yourself
- add one image - some jpeg - and see where the Copy Bundle Resources moves it. I recall that it just gets moved to the main bundle directory but again not sure.
- create an empty Run Script, and check the box to dump the environment - you will see all the various defines there and can find the one that points to the proper directory (so you can use it in your script)
- using the above find the variable that points to the top level project directory, so you can navigate to your images folders
- now code your run script, using the variables, find all images folders in your project, and essentially copy them into the appropriate place in the app bundle. You want to use the variables as the paths are different for the simulator and real app.

You will find example of writing 'Run Scripts' here and on the web. I can never remember which of those Xcode environmental variables to use so always just dump a set and then poke around. With any one name, you can google it and find the Apple docs that provide further info on it.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion, but in my case the images need to be divided into folders as it's the contents of each individual folder that are queried. How could I make sure the original directory structure is maintained?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was selecting **"Create folder references for any added folders"** when adding my folders, and then trying to access the images via

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
                                                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], imageName]];
```

But this works only if the image is sitting in the root directory of the .app, which is what happens if you select **"Create groups for any added folders"**.

In my case, I wanted to preserve the original directory structure, so I solved the problem by including the path to the image in the parameter I gave to `imageWithContentsOfFile`:

```
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name-of-my-images-rootdirectory/%@/%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", subdirectoryName], [normalImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], imageName]];
```